# Best use of database for storing large scientific data sets

Tags: mysql, database, scientific-computing

In my primary role, I handle laboratory testing data files that can contain upwards of 2000 parameters for each unique test condition. These files are generally stored and processed as CSV formatted files, but that becomes very unwieldy when working with 6000+ files with 100+ rows each.

I am working towards a future database storage and query solution to improve access and efficiency, but I am stymied by the row length limitation of MySQL (specifically MariaDB 5.5.60 on RHEL 7.5). I am using MYISAM instead of InnoDB, which has allowed me to get to around 1800 mostly-double formatted data fields. This version of MariaDB forces dynamic columns to be numbered, not named, and I cannot currently upgrade to MariaDB 10+ due to administrative policies.

Should I be looking at a NoSQL database for this application, or is there a better way to handle this data? How do others handle many-variable data sets, especially numeric data?

For an example of the CSV files I am trying to import, see below. The identifier I have been using is an amalgamation of TEST, RUN, TP forming a 12-digit unsigned bigint key.

Example File:
RUN     ,TP      ,TEST    ,ANGLE   ,SPEED   ,...
1.000000E+00,1.000000E+00,5.480000E+03,1.234567E+01,6.345678E+04,...

Example key:
548000010001 <-- Test = 5480, Run = 1, TP = 1

I appreciate any input you have.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity comes from the fact that you have to handle a huge number of data, not from the fact that they are split over many files with many rows.

Using a database storage & query system will superficially hide some of this complexity, but at the expense of complexity at several other levels, as you have already experienced, including obstacles that are out of your control like changing versions and conservative admins. Database storage & query system are made for other application scenarios where they have advantages that are not pertinent for your case.

You should seriously reconsider leaving your data in files, i.e. use your file system as your database storage system. Possibly, transcribe you CSV input into a modern self-documenting data format like YAML or HDF5. For queries, you may be better off writing scripts or programs that directly access those files, instead of writing SQL queries.